# Math in development(((

Tags: android, kotlin, math, geometry, location

Sup, guys! I have a task to calculate coordinates of continuation line between points A & B. I have a code each calculate distance between these points, and I have tangent of angle for calculating next points D and F. Thanks for any help [image: what_i_need][image: maincase]

```
`val pointA = LatLng(a.latitude, a.longitude)
    val pointB = LatLng(b.latitude, b.longitude)
    val pointC = LatLng(a.latitude, b.longitude)//for calculating
    val polylineOptions = PolylineOptions()
        .add(pointA)
        .add(pointB)
        .add(pointC)
        .add(pointA)
    val distanceAB = getKmFromLatLong(pointA.latitude, pointA.longitude, pointB.latitude, pointB.longitude)
    val distanceBC = getKmFromLatLong(pointB.latitude, pointB.longitude, pointC.latitude, pointC.longitude)
    val distanceCA = getKmFromLatLong(pointC.latitude, pointC.longitude, pointA.latitude, pointA.longitude)
    val tang = distanceBC/distanceCA
    println("__ distanceAB $distanceAB")
    println("__ distanceBC $distanceBC")
    println("__ distanceCA $distanceCA")
    println("__ tang $tang")`
```

Comment: [Point-slope formula](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-point-slope.html)

Comment: Also note that the earth is not flat, so calculating distance between 2 points (especially over a significant distances) is more than just calculating 2d euclidean distance.

Comment: Should be using spherical coordinates.  Google for them if you don't know what those are.  Your functions getKmFromLatLong suggest that somebody is calculating the distances correctly.  I would wonder about your projection onto the flat map.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys! Point-slope formula - rules

```
  private fun generateNeedingPoints(a: LatLng, b: LatLng): List<LatLng> {
    setScreenBounds()
    val c: LatLng
    val d: LatLng
    val longitudeC = if (a.longitude < b.longitude) northEast.longitude else southWest.longitude
    val longitudeD = if (a.longitude < b.longitude) southWest.longitude else northEast.longitude
    c = calculateEdgeButton(a, b, longitudeC)
    d = calculateEdgeButton(b, a, longitudeD)
    return mutableListOf(d, a, b, c)
}
```

`

```
private fun calculateEdgeButton(a: LatLng, b: LatLng, edgeLng: Double, distortionCoefficient:Double = 1.0): LatLng{
    val longChange = b.longitude - a.longitude
    val latChange = b.latitude - a.latitude
    val slope = latChange / longChange
    val longChangePointC = edgeLng - b.longitude
    val latChangePointC = longChangePointC * slope
    val latitudeC = b.latitude + latChangePointC
    return LatLng(latitudeC * distortionCoefficient, edgeLng)
}
```

`